# error: incompatible types when initializing type 'char *' using type 'double'

Tags: sql, c, sqlite, char

Good afternoon, 
I've got this code below:

```
double bd_sacar_imc(double altura, double peso) {
sqlite3 *db;
char *zErrMsg = 0;
int rc;

char *sql = ("SELECT %lf/(%lf * %lf);", peso, altura, altura);

rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, callback, 0, &zErrMsg);

if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
    fprintf(stderr, "SQL error: %s\n", zErrMsg);
    sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
    return 0;
} else {
    fprintf(stdout, "Consulta creada con exito\n");
    return peso / (altura * altura);
}};
```

However, I get this error:

```
..\BD\bd.c:170:14: error: incompatible types when initializing type 'char *' using type 'double' char *sql = ("SELECT %lf /( %lf * %lf);", peso, altura, altura);
```

What might be happening?

Comment: `char *sql = (...);` I think you forgot `*printf` function associated with the parentheses here.  You'll also want to allocate some space to `sql` if you're planning on writing something into it.

Comment: There are so many errors that I dont know where to start. Maybe you can start at the manuals (https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/exec.html), taking a careful thought about this: _The application must ensure that the 1st parameter to sqlite3_exec() is a valid and open database connection._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to build a string.  For that you can use [`snprintf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf).

```
char sql[64];
int size = snprintf(sql, 64, "SELECT %lf/(%lf * %lf);", peso, altura, altura);
```

Note that I kept the return value.  This is to handle any future error where you modify a statement in a way that might result in buffer overflow or other error.  You can probably just deal with this by using a debug assertion, as this pre-sized string should be large enough to hold the intended SQL.

```
if (size < 0 || size >= 64) {
    assert(0);
    return 0;
}
```

However, since you are using sqlite library, you should instead use the proper methods to prepare a statement and *bind* values to it, rather than inserting the values into the string yourself.